# Monitoring connection to an internal server

Tags: networking

I have an internal company server, and there are a few internal apps that are hosted on it.

The problem is that the connection is not very stable, so I want to know how is the connection in a time series manner, for how long the server has been down, at what period of time the server is down, that kind of information.

To be more specific, I want to know whether a particular port on that server is accessible, because the app requires a dedicated port to communicate with the rest of the clients in the network.

**Edit: Note that the port and the app is only accessible from the intranet.**

Is there any software/ web apps that do this?

Comment: There are plenty of them, dependent upon the service/application you want to monitor. Do you just want to know if the server is alive and accessible or do you have more complex needs?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I want to know whether a particular port on that server is accessible, because the app requires a dedicated port to communicate with the rest of the clients in the network.

Answer (score 1):

Here are just a few of the many that offer external monitoring for standard or custom ports:

http://www.serviceuptime.com/free_monitoring.php

http://www.siteuptime.com/

http://www.remotemonitoringservices.com/monitor_overview.php

Comment: Hmm, seems to me that they are all dealing with internet apps. What about intranet apps? My apps are not accessible from the outside.

Comment: In that case: http://www.serverscheck.com/monitoring_software. http://www.nagios.org. http://www.poweradmin.com/ServerMonitor. and a billion more results at google: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=server+monitoring&cp=9&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=0&aqi=&aql=&oq=server+mo&pbx=1&fp=e5fa828e5bee98d1